# I can't get JSON object from response to getJSON ( jQuery )

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I'm new to JSON , I have php page (server side) which include information formatted in JSON and I want to get these information in client side ( html page ) , I found an example using this function 'getJSON' in jQuery to do the same , but I think I'm missing something when using it because I'm not getting the response I want (Actually I'm getting nothing) 
this is the php code :

```
    <?php
    //header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    ?>

    {
        "file": 
        {
            "filename" : "Test.txt",
            "fileCreatingDate" : "15-7-2013",
            "fileModifyDate" : "20-8-2013",
            "filesize" : "3002345",
            "filetype" : "Text",
        }
    }
```

I believe I should mention that this was php page with xml content and what I did is changing the xml format to json format , and here is the client side code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
              <html>
              <head>
                  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
                  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
              </head>

              <body>


              <div id="response">
                  <p id="responseParagraph">Base text</p>
              </div>

              <script>
              //172.25.10.99 is the server ip
                  $.getJSON('http://172.25.10.99/list2.php',
                      function(data) {
                          $('#responseParagraph').append("<p>"+data.responseMessage+"           </p>");
                      });
              </script>
              </body>
              </html>
```

I would like to receive JSON object to be parsed later , what I'm trying to say is : I want do something close to xmlhttprequest and parsing the response but in JSON instead .
could you please help ?? I'd really appreciate it .

Comment: you have some white space before the json output starts you may want to try after removing that

Comment: You've got a stray comma after the "filetype" property in your JSON. You should check the browser error console when working on things like this, because that will let you see the actual response and any errors detected. *edit* white space is not a problem.

Answer (score 5):

The comma behind `"filetype" : "Text",` makes your json invalid. Remove that and you should get your json parsed. You can use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to verify that your json is correct.

Comment: I removed the comma and then I verified my json using jsonlint , my json is valid , yet I'm facing the same problem : can't get the response , any other ideas please ??

Comment: Do what DevZer0 says below too. `data` is the array that the json string specifies, so `data.responseMessage` doesn't exist.

Comment: sorry but I tried that too and still no result , any possible help again ??

Comment: console.log `data` and see what it is.

Answer (score 2):

i also noticed that your not using the `key` that is in your `json` output.

```
 $.getJSON('http://172.25.10.99/list2.php',
    function(data) {
        $('#responseParagraph').append("<p>"+data.file.filename+"</p>");
    });
```